# Webpack angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having problems with ui router implementation in my webpack app.

I downloaded it:

```
npm install --save @uirouter/angularjs
```

Then just in my app.js file:

```
const css = require('./src/style/app.scss');
var angular = require('angular');
var uiRouter = require('@uirouter/angularjs');


var ngModule = angular.module('app', ['uiRouter']);
require stuff.

ngModule.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider){ 

    $stateProvider // routing 

    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('program', {
        url: '/program',
        templateUrl: 'program.html',
        controller: 'ProgramCtrl'
    })
    .state('administration', {
        url: '/administration',
        templateUrl: 'adminNetworks.html',
        controller: 'NetworkCtrl'
    })
    .state('automatic', {
        url: '/automatic',
        templateUrl: 'automatic.html',
        controller: 'AutomaticCtrl'
    })
    .state('registry', {
        url: '/registry',
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('otherwise', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
});
```

But still I've got error "Module 'uiRouter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.".

I know that angular-ui-router doesn't work anymore so I downloaded this and insert code from ui router github.

Well I just in this way used firstly angular-route (routeProvider) and it works.. but i need modals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should install

```
npm install --save angular-ui-router
```

and the dependency should be

```
var ngModule = angular.module('app', ['ui-router']);
```

Comment: When I'm installing angular-ui-router, in my console I've got this issue: this npm package "angular-ui-router" has been renamed to "@uirouter/angularjs" . Please update ur package.json. See github ui router for details

Comment: what issue did you get

Comment: update package json as mentioned here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3468

Comment: Thanks, and what about require code? Because var uiRouter = require('@uirouter/angularjs'); with uiRouter in module can't work still

Comment: Okay it works with this require after upload npm. I've got another issue, because it can't find @uirouter in my folder app, Ill try to solve it

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@uirouter/angularjs" and Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@uirouter/angularjs' in 'C:\Projekty\webpack1'. Seems like I've got a good implementation but wrong folder requirement.

It's weird, because when I had "var uiRouter = require('angular-route'); webpack can find it. But cant @uirouter

Comment: instead of require try using import

Comment: import uirouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';

Comment: Uploaded packages and npm again. Added import uiRouter from '@uirouter/angularjs'; with uiRouter in module. Still same error, just cant resolve it from my folder

Comment: Webpack is so a problematic, I really dont know how to figure this out. I put there node_modules/@uirouter and other paths but its not a problem i guess? Is possible that this error is because of / in opposite side? Xd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162669/discussion-between-kondziowsky-and-sajeetharan).